# Nutch problems executing crawl on Windows

Tags: windows, web-crawler, nutch

I am trying to get nutch 1.11 to execute a crawl. I am using cygwin to run these commands in Windows 8.

I have put *hadoop-core jar* into lib folder but when I try to run a crawl I obtain:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.cli.OptionBuilder.withArgPattern(Ljava/lang/String;I)Lorg/apache/commons/cli/OptionBuilder;
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.buildGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:207)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.parseGeneralOptions(GenericOptionsParser.java:370)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.(GenericOptionsParser.java:153)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.GenericOptionsParser.(GenericOptionsParser.java:138)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:59)
>           at org.apache.nutch.crawl.Injector.main(Injector.java:369)

The command is

> $ bin/nutch inject crawl/crawldb urls